# How to fix size Error in data frame arrange

Tags: r, rstudio-server

I ran this code in R Studio

```
Output<- data.frame(participant_df, GroupSize_df, PSE_df, slope_df)
Output_sorted <- Output[arrange(Output, desc(participant_df))]
```

And I got this error:

```
Error: Error in `arrange()`: ℹ In argument: `..1 = participant_df`. 
Caused by error: ! `..1` must be size 172 or 1, not 86.
```

How to fix this error?

I want to put my Output data frame in alphabetical order according to the strings in the `participant` variable

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To increase chances of getting answers, consider editing your question according to [ask] and [mre]. Taking the [tour] is also quite informative. In particular, a small but representative sample of input data might help. What is `..1`?